# что не так с кодом при добавления элементов в массив больше 5 значений

Tags: c++, vector, struct

Есть некая структура хранящая в себе std::vector

```
struct TRemoteQuestData
{
    bool bActivate;
    int nIndex;
    int nQuestID;
    bool bPreQuestCheckType;
    std::vector<int> nVecPreQuestCondition;
    TEventCondition GainCondition;
};
```

в этом коде когда достигает более пяти элемента в массиве происходит креш

```
TRemoteQuestData *pData = new TRemoteQuestData;
memset( pData, 0, sizeof(TRemoteQuestData) );

for( int j=0; j<10; j++ ) 
{
    int nPreQuestID = pTable->GetFieldFromLablePtr( iIdx, sFieldNum._PreQuestCondition[j] )->GetInteger();
    if( 0 == nPreQuestID )
        continue;

    pData->nVecPreQuestCondition.push_back( nPreQuestID );
}
```

крэш с надписью

```
Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения.
**_Pnext** было 0x8.
```

но если прописать так то этой ошибки нету

```
TRemoteQuestData *pData = new TRemoteQuestData;
memset( pData, 0, sizeof(TRemoteQuestData) );


pData->nVecPreQuestCondition.resize(10);
for( int j=0; j<10; j++ ) 
{
    int nPreQuestID = pTable->GetFieldFromLablePtr( iIdx, sFieldNum._PreQuestCondition[j] )->GetInteger();
    if( 0 == nPreQuestID )
        continue;

    pData->nVecPreQuestCondition[j] = nPreQuestID;
}
```

объясните пожалуйста почему push_back крэшится и как это исправить, или все таки использовать 2-й вариант?

Comment: У вектора `std::vector<int>` есть конструктор, предназначенный для его инициализации. Нельзя забивать вектор нулями с помощью `memset`. Имею ввиду не сами данные, которые хранит вектор, а сам объект типа `std::vector<int>`. У вас это член структуры `TRemoteQuestData` — `nVecPreQuestCondition`.

Comment: Да и объекты типа `bool` также не следует занулять `memset`'ом. Не факт, что значение `false` есть последовательность нулей.

Comment: живу и учусь  спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Вы сами уже всё исправили. Лучше использовать второй вариант. Он более правильный (с точки зрения кода). Тем более у std::vector есть инициализирующий конструктор, в котором нельзя использовать 0 с помощью memset.

Comment: memset остался с предыдушей версии компелятора VS 2008 или 2005 точно не знаю,  resize задает ровно 10 значений а предедуший вариант был не всегда 10 а в зовисимости того что nPreQuestID не равен нулю

Comment: Ясно. Но лучше использовать второй вариант.